# Handle null value in json with flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch quotes from [here](https://type.fit/api/quotes)

but some values in the JSON are null, how can I handle this in flutter?

I have the error message:`_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Null')`

API call method:

```
Future fetchAllQuotes() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://type.fit/api/quotes'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var quotes = [];
    for (var aQuote in jsonData) {
      Quote quote = Quote(
        text: aQuote['text'],
        author: aQuote['author'],//the error is caused here
      );

      quotes.add(quote);
    }
    
    return quotes;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to fetch quotes');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution

```
author: aQuote['author'] ?? 'null'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. I did the same solution before and it didn't work, I probably was messing something.

Comment: @YassineBENNKHAY Great quotes though :D

Comment: Wouldn't it be more succinct to write `aQuote['author'] ?? 'null'`?

Comment: @RichardHeap I refactor my answer based on your comment. I wasn't aware of this dart ?? operator, but it looks good

Comment: You can also do this way. author: aQuote['author'] ??  ''

Comment: @RichardHeap yes I did `aQuote['author'] ?? 'Unknown'`, thanks.